# File not found, even though the directory is correct

Tags: python, file, directory

I am currently trying to make a game, and I am importing an image for a button from a the same folder the python file is from. The method:

```
dirname, filename = os.path.split(os.path.abspath(sys.argv[0]))
imagepath = os.path.join(dirname, "redvase.png")
vase1 = Button(root, relief=FLAT, background="white", image=imagepath)
vase1.place(x=330,y=240,height=30,width=30)
```

The output (imagepath) comes out as `C:\Users\ - - \Desktop\Pythonproject\redvase.png`

My file is at that exact path, but I still get an error saying that that file does not exist.

```
vase1 = Button(root, relief=FLAT, background="white", image=imagepath)
......
_tkinter.TclError: image "C:\Users\- -\Desktop\Pythonproject\redvase.png" doesn't exist
```

If it helps, I am using Windows and Python 3.4.3.

Comment: Are you 100% certain it's a png and not say, a jpg and that the name is spelled correctly?

Comment: have you also checked the file permissons for the file?

Comment: Can you open the file using the Python `open()` function? Are you sure that the `image=` parameter takes a file name, and not something like an `Image` object? (I'm unfamiliar with TkInter at that level.)

Comment: The Tk library doesn't support any other formats than `.gif`. Have you tried using a .gif?

Comment: @GregHewgill Ah of course - huge brain-fart.

Comment: The easiest way to use non-GIF files is to use Pillow. It knows how to read an `Image` in all kinds of formats, and create an `ImageTk` that Tkinter knows how to use. Usually [`PhotoImage`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageTk.html#PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage) is what you want.

Comment: `"- -"` is not the same as `" - - "`

Comment: If you `print(imagepath )` what do you see?

Comment: [This documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/button.html) says you have to pass an [image object](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/images.html).

Comment: Is that even a legal directory name?

Comment: @PeterWood Thanks for the help! I looked it up and I used a picture object.

Comment: Thanks for the help on the issue everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image attribute for a button takes an input of an Image object, not a path to an image file.
In order to get an image, you can use a PhotoImage:

```
photo=PhotoImage(file="redvase.gif")
vase1 = Button(root, relief=FLAT, background="white", image=photo)
```